# Magento Valid url redirects to 404

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing some issue with product url. Url seems to look fine but some times it's get redirected to 404 and the url-key value in address bar is getting replaced with 'null'.

I am not able to find any clue why its happening.

Can you any body suggest proper method to debug such issue?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically URL rewrite issue. Check if the url rewrites are enabled: System> Configuration > Web > Search Engine Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites.
And if the problem still persists do check your exception.log file

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this is a 2 year old post, but I had this issue today...

**all previously valid product urls got a 404 error**

after a lot of failed attempts of figuring out what was going on I asked someone to take a look, to which they replied: Err, What's wrong? ... 
apparently everything was fine, but my own user's session/cookie had bad data, or something.

Removing the bad cookie fixed this.

I have no idea specifically what it was because I did not think of keeping a backup of the bad cookie/session data to investigate.

But I'm guessing it had something to do with my session's customer id or user id

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: 
General error: 1032 Can't find record in 'report_viewed_product_index',
query was: INSERT INTO `report_viewed_product_index`
```